# C# very slow StreamReader

Tags: c#, performance, streamreader, csv

I'm using some not optimal code written by me... :-|

I have following code:

```
string fmtLine = "";
            string[] splitedFmtLine;
            int counterFMTlines = 0;

            foreach (string fmtF in fmtFiles)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fmtF))
                {
                    while ((fmtLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(counterFMTlines++);
                        foreach (L3Message message in rez)
                        {
                            splitedFmtLine = Regex.Split(fmtLine, "\t");

                            if (message.Time == splitedFmtLine[0])
                            {
                                message.ScramblingCode = splitedFmtLine[7];      
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tested this code when List was empty and there was only one file (tab delimited, 280000 lines), and even then it took lifetime (1 min) to go through all 280000 lines of my file. That means that execution skipped foreach loop where is my List of myObjs.

I cannot understand why it took so long?

As example, I was filling my List of myObjs (tree hierarchy) with different text file (source file) but bigger than this tab delimited(tab delimited: 16MB, source file: 36MB) and it took only second versus this 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the problem writing to the console, you also have a **O(m*n) runtime** for n being the number of lines in the file and m being the number of messages. This is bad if m or n is big. You can reduce this to an O(n) operation by using a `Dictionary` instead and eliminating the inner loop.

You can put your messages in a `Dictionary`, using the Time as a key. In the loop you only have to ask the dictionary for the messages at a specific time:

```
        string fmtLine = "";
        string[] splitedFmtLine;
        int counterFMTlines = 0;

        var messageTimes = new Dictionary<string, LinkedList<L3Message>>();
        foreach (L3Message message in rez)
        {
            LinkedList<L3Message> list=null;
            messageTimes.TryGetValue(message.Time, out list);

            list = list ?? new LinkedList<L3Message>();

            list.AddLast(message);
            messageTimes[message.Time] = list;
        }

        foreach (string fmtF in fmtFiles)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fmtF))
            {
                while ((fmtLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(counterFMTlines++);
                    splitedFmtLine = fmtLine.Split('\t');

                    LinkedList<L3Message> messageList = null;
                    messageTimes.TryGetValue(splitedFmtLine[0], out messageList);

                    if(messageList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var message in messageList)
                        {
                            message.ScramblingCode = splitedFmtLine[7];                                
                        }
                        messageTimes.Remove(splitedFmtLine[0]); //see comments
                    }

                    if(messageTimes.Count==0) break; //see comments
                }
            }
            if(messageTimes.Count==0) break; //see comments
        }
```

This should be super fast.

**Edit:** I changed the example so that it supports cases where there is more than one message for one time.

**Edit2:** I added an optimization based on the fact that message time and ScramblingCode always correlate (see comments).

Comment: This looks great... I'll tested when my VS profiler is finished.

Comment: Thx for edit... Here is catch, in FMTfile, there is multiple lines with same time, but I need only one (for same time ScramblingCode is same). Do u think that here is some possible optimisation?

Comment: Can there be more than one message with the same time where you have to set the scrambling code?

Comment: You could add a messageTimes.Remove(splitedFmtLine[0]) inside the if statement. Like this you wouldn't find any messages the next time a line is read with a time that is already updated. At the end of the foreach you can then check if messageTimes is empty and in this case break out of the loop completely (because all messages are updated already).

Comment: Yes! There can be more messages with same time I'm filling my List<L3Message> depend of how many params are in source file, if in sourcefile(text file with tree hierarchy oriented lines) are one of params, than i created L3Message obj with that param and all his subparams (they are in tree hierarchy in file)... here is problem which i solved (tabdelimited output in that quest. is not my fmtFile, FMTfile here is second of input file creating my L3Message obj) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887506/c-sharp-tree-data-structure-making-output

Comment: Okay, then see my suggestion above to optimize this more. also you should accept the answer in the post you linked and also this answer, if it helped you. Like this you not only get points (reputation) on this page, but also people are more willing to help you in the future.

Comment: I give you accept of answer, because of code . . . And this guy in first answer also make good point. I need to get this vote up possibility :-)

Comment: There is problem... Output tabdelimited file with latest edit is different than one with previous edit. I'm trying to see what happens...

Answer (score 8):

You are writing 280.000 times to the console which is very slow. Remove the console output. Also, use string.Split('\t') which is way faster than this particular regex call.

Comment: As @usr said, get rid of console.write in the loop, move it to the first loop with files if you want to have some kind of information at runtime.

Comment: thx for info, I know that Console out affect on performance, but i thought that Regex expressions are more optimal than string methods...

Comment: No, Regex methods have a non-trivial amount of overhead. I have never seen a case where a manual string operation could not be made faster than a regex. Regex'es are convenience features.

Comment: Manual string operations tend to be more memory intensive though, because you create a lot of string, that you don't need (assuming you are doing multiple string operations).

Comment: @aKzenT this can always be avoided. In the extreme case you are re-coding the regex'es state machine. If performance is important, you can always get on-par with regex and most of the time better. A regex is just a runtime-generated method which you can reproduce your self. You can even save a compiled regex to an assembly on disk.

Comment: @usr of course, but then again you could code directly in assembler getting even more performance ;-) at the end it's always a trade-off between performance and complexity of the solution. In many cases Regex provides an acceptable performance and reduce code complexity.